# .net MVC default routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Recently I came across this question:

I have this route from RouteConfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

 routes.MapRoute(
     "",
     "{controller}/{action}/{productName}",
     new
     {
        action = "Show",
        productName = "aaaa"
     }
   );
}
```

Now they need to add a routing to make sure all products that's no longer exist or have IDs changed will be displayed to a product.

The recommended solution is to have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{action}/{productName}",
    new { action = "Show", productName = "aaa" }
);
```

but with no controller in the default value for route, it will throw an exception of

> The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which
>   is required.

So it is possible to define a route with default routing but no controller specified?

Comment: No its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen is correct, it is not possible to make a route without specifying controller. However, it is possible to use a default controller value and not pass the value for `{controller}` in the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{action}/{productName}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Show", productName = "aaa" }
);
```

Also, you should be careful how you specify your other defaults. What you have defined here are optional values for `action` and `productName`, which default to what you specified in the `defaults`.

Therefore, the following URLs will function:

- `/Product`
- `/Product/Show`

Usually it doesn't make any sense to make a "default" product. It would make more sense to make `action` and `productName` into required parameters in the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{action}/{productName}",
    new { controller = "Product" }
);
```